# Javascript shows non-arabic characters when retrieving from another page

Tags: javascript, html, arabic-support

I used an external page to get information from the user,

[Picture:Getting info from the user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8L3TS.png)

This information contains Arabic and English actually.

I use this code for that :

```html
 
                    <form type=get action="http://ershadchem.yoo7.com/post?f=16&mode=newtopic">
  <table>
    <tr>
    <td>First Name:</td>
    <td><input type=text name=firstname size=10></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Last Name:</td>
    <td><input type=text name=lastname size=10></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Age:</td>
    <td><input type=text name=age size=10></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan=2><input type=submit value="Submit">
    </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
      </form>
```

when the user enter information (may be Arabic, English or both), I use them in another page by a JavaScript code:

```js
                                       
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
                                                      
                                                      
  function getParams(){
  var idx = document.URL.indexOf('?');
  var params = new Array();
  if (idx != -1) {
    var pairs = document.URL.substring(idx+1, document.URL.length).split('&');
  for (var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++){
    nameVal = pairs[i].split('=');
    params[nameVal[0]] = nameVal[1];
    }
  }
  return params;
 }
params = getParams();
firstname = unescape(params["firstname"]);
lastname = unescape(params["lastname"]);
age = unescape(params["age"]);
document.write("firstname = " + firstname + "<br>");
document.write("lastname = " + lastname + "<br>");
document.write("age = " + age + "<br>");

var getenwanid = document.getElementById("enwanid");
var getenwanid0 = document.getElementById("enwanid0");



</script>
```

The result is perfect in English in the page :

[Picture:English information is retrieved perfectly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZU1s.png)

But when user enters information in Arabic:

[Picture:type info in Arabic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKmz4.png)

the result is non-arabic characters:
[Picture:Non-arabic characters are shown in picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUZfx.png)

I hope I could get an edit for the codes that helps me show Arabic characters properly.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`unescape` is broken. Use `decodeURIComponent` instead.

Comment: But (+) is shown between each word. How can I remove it?